# Customizing the Cloze Card Type - Having two cards in a card type

Tags: anki

I am having two cards in my card type, which I created based on the cloze deletion type, by copying it.

If the position of my card is 1, than as described in the documentation, `{{cloze:MyDataField}}` works, as I like. But if the position of the card is two, the cloze deletion extension seems to be disabled.

On my card on position two I only need to display the sentence, without the `{{c1::word1}}`, ...., `{{cN::wordN}}`  tags but with the words, wrapped by those.

Is there maybe a way to create two cards using a close type in my card type's template? Or is there maybe a way to get the plain text of my fields so that I can parse it with JavaScript? Or can I maybe somehow just display the content of the field, ignoring `{{c1` expressions, but displaying the content?

Comment: I would also like to get this to work, but unfortunately the fmod_uncloze function never seems to be called. Even if it did work, it wouldn't help me on Anki droid would it? So.... the only work around would be to edit and compile my own version of Anki?? pfft! I think I'll just have to add to fields, one with cloze and one without. Pooh!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write an Anki add-on to do this, if you are familiar with Python 2. Cards compiled with a Desktop Anki with this add-on installed will work on AnkiWeb without displaying gibberish. Here is an (untested!) add-on that *should* register a special `fmod` that allows you to write `{{uncloze:fieldname}}` to get the plain text sans `{{cn::` and `}}` marks.

```
import re

from anki.hooks import addHook
from anki.template.template import Template

"""Adds support for the unclose Moustache tag.
Blame wizzwizz4 if this does / doesn't work.
Modified to work for <anki_version> by <your_name>."""

open_cloze_regex = re.compile(r"{{c\d+::")

def fmod_uncloze(txt, extra, context, tag, tag_name):
    field_name = tag_name[8:]  # Strip off "uncloze:"
    field_content = Template("{{" + field_name + "}}", context).render()
    return open_cloze_regex.sub("", field_content).replace("}}", "")

addHook("fmod_uncloze", fmod_uncloze)
```

Put this in a file in the Anki add-ons directory then restart Anki to install it.

Much of this code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844796/5223757).

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know add-ons are that well integrated into Anki. But I have a problem, I have tried using this in Anki 2.1 by putting it in it's own folder and copying the code into __init__.py. It shows up in my add-ons but when I write {{uncloze:Fieldname}} and try it, the cloze just disappears altogether. A card with "I am {{c1::clozed}}" becomes "I am" at review with back-side "I am ". Am I misunderstanding the expected behavior here, did I do something wrong, or did something critical change with Anki 2.1?

Comment: @Yannick I could have just done it wrong. Actually, now that I come to think of it... I think I've re-invented the wheel. I'll just edit...

Comment: I can't get the text: prefix to work with cloze. But that is probably just a problem on my end. I was actually looking at this answer to get ideas on how to write a certain add-on myself to tamper with cloze cards (it might very well become a question in the near future). Is there any extensive documentation on all the add-on functionality that you use to write the add-ons here, or do you just go through the source (sorry for going off-topic).

Comment: It didn't work because it's supposed to strip _text_, not close. :-/ I think the strategy is: 1. Check Stack Overflow ([tag:anki] tag). 2. Ask a Stack Overflow question. 3. Ping me in chat (optional). 4. Check the source code. 5. <del>Email</del> Post a message on the Anki support site.

Comment: @Yannick Try now.

Comment: Still unable to get it to work, maybe just adding a simple use case, since you say you are working with Python 2 (though it is valid Python 3 code) maybe this does not work in Anki 2.1 anymore? I don't have 2.0 on my machine anymore. Or maybe adding a list of actions to perform to test usage (1. make card of type x, 2. replace {{Front}} with {{uncloze:Front}} etc.) I feel like at this point it is a problem with my setup, sorry for that.

Comment: @Yannick This is a 2.0 addon, not a 2.1 addon. I don't know how to use 2.1, since I've never managed to get it to install. I'd love to use it though, if only for Python 3.