# Anki - What should I hook to add my own field descriptors?

Tags: python, hook, anki

Similarly to `{{field}}` and `{{text:field}}`, I am trying to create my own field descriptor. In order to do this, I need to know what function to hook. I do not know whether Anki pre-compiles cards into HTML or produces them on-the-fly during study, so I don't know where to begin to look for this function - I haven't found any existing add-ons that do this so I can't look at how they implemented it.

What function should I hook to implement special field descriptors in cards?

Answer (score 3):

Anki pre-compiles to HTML, and I have found the function that deals with "Moustache tags" [in template.py](https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/anki/template/template.py#L180).

By registering the hook `fmod_<modifier>` with a function taking a filter parameter `txt` and (fixed) parameters `extra`, `content`, `tag` and `tag_name` one can register a modifier for that name.

That last parameter, `tag_name`, is probably the one you want, as it is a string that contains everything between the `{{` and `}}` marks.